# Problems with Minimizing to Tray

Tags: c#, winforms, icons, system-tray, trayicon

In my windows forms application (C#) I have such code:

```
            private void frm_main_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized) && (checkBox1.Checked))
        {
            this.ShowInTaskbar = false;

            notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
        }
    }

    private void notifyIcon1_DoubleClick(object Sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
        {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        }
        else
        {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        }

        this.Activate();
    }
```

My publick form has Double click handler             `notifyIcon1.DoubleClick += new System.EventHandler(this.notifyIcon1_DoubleClick);`

When minimized app still apears in taskbar, how to change that? I want that on minimized state it only would be in system tray. Why does this coce deosnt work?

Comment: Have you actually hooked up the notifyIcon1_MouseDoubleClick handler to the notifyIcon1 object?

Comment: Yup just did that, and now it works, but still down know how to remove app from taskbar.

Comment: Have you verified that the value of this.WindowState is actually Minimized when frm_main_Resize executes?

Comment: Not really, how could I do that?

Comment: You can set a breakpoint inside the frm_main_Resize method and debug the application.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using similar code in my project which is working and you don't need hide and show:

```
private void frm_main_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized && checkBox1.Checked)
    {
        this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Also try to handle `MouseClick` Event instead of `DoubleClick`

```
  private void notifyIcon1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
  {
     if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left && e.Clicks == 2)
     {
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        this.ShowInTaskbar = true;
        notifyIcon1.Visible = false;
        this.Activate();
     }
  }
```

Comment: For show application from tray is better to use event `MouserDoubleClick`. That event to show application use such programs as Skype, Microsoft Security Essentials, Origin and many other programs.

Comment: @Epsil0neR how do you know what they are using? they are not open source. Clicking twice on them doesn't mean they are using DoubleClick event

Comment: That doesn't make a sence. Many programs you can't show from tray with single click, so in that case he should use event `MouseDoubleClick`.

Comment: @Epsil0neR please look at my code better, I'm handling double click in my function. If the thing would be so obvious, the OP's code would work. Btw. there are 2 events, DoubleClick and MouseDoubleClick. Which would you use?

Comment: I tryed event `MouseClick` and I saw, that e.Cliks alvays are equal 1, i even can't get e.clicks > 1 with mouseclicker application, so your code won't work properly. I used 2 labels in WinForm with MouseClick event that code is here: http://pastebin.com/QcjSAxaC